# Unable to parse an element from eBay via BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape "number of items sold" on eBay but for some reason I cannot. I already have the title, price, and all I need is total_sold_price which I am unable to attain. Every time I run my code, I just get a blank for total_sold_price.

```
try:
    title_selenium = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="itemTitle"]').text
except:
    title_selenium = ""
try:
    price_selenium = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="prcIsum"]').text.strip().split()
except:
    price_selenium = ""
try:
    total_sold_price_BeautifulSoup = soup.find('span', {'class': 'vi-qtyS-hot-red'}).text
except:
    total_sold_price_BeautifulSoup = ""
```

My entire code: https://pastebin.com/bu8HgCDZ

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it for you. You need to make the `soup` call inside your loop.

Note: I am using this path '../chromedriver', please change it to your path before running the code.

Code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome('../chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=watches&_sacat=0&_pgn=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
driver.maximize_window()

tempList = []

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if 'itm' in link['href']:
        print(link['href'])
        tempList.append(link['href'])

array_length = len(tempList)

for i in range(array_length):
    driver.get(tempList[i])
    timeout = 5

    try:
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="itemTitle"]'))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Timed out waiting for page to load")

    try:
        title_selenium = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="itemTitle"]').text
    except:
        title_selenium = ""
    try:
        price_selenium = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="prcIsum"]').text.strip().split()
    except:
        price_selenium = ""
   #you need to call soup here due to your loop structure
   soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
   try:
        total_sold_price_BeautifulSoup = soup.find('span', {'class': 'vi-qtyS-hot-red'}).text
    except:
        total_sold_price_BeautifulSoup = ""

    print("title: ", title_selenium)
    print("price: ", price_selenium)
    print("total_sold_price: ", total_sold_price_BeautifulSoup)
    print("\n")

    i+=1




driver.close()
```